# Spring Boot import trust-store

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-boot

I need to import a trust-store in Spring Boot without using System.setProperty, but only the application.properties file.
This is the structure of my project:
[image]

I add this string:
**server.ssl.trust-store = cacerts**, but when i run the spring boot application i have this error message:

**ERROR 6576 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null**

Someone have solved this?

Comment: You should include relevant code in your question.

Comment: Is a simple application, with only a static html page, i need to import truststore because this page is protect by CAS

Comment: here is more information about the context:
We try to configure the embedded servlet container (tomcat) to use a specific trust-store, in order for our application to consume a RESTful webservice over https.
We configured application.properties as recommended in the doc, but we get this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution, the property file need value for trust and key store not for only one of this, if one of this property is null the application throws exception

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and although the accepted answer did help, it implies that you have to generate a key and activate SSL for your application.
If you only want to pass information of the trust store for peer verification without activating SSL for your own application (which is okay for test but not in production), you must use java properties (not the spring boot one). Something like this worked for me :

```
java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password your-appplication.jar
```